# auto show data after search

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to my code to do is if i search for batchcode the datas that equals to that batchcode will automatically shows in the texboxes basically each batchcodes has (4)datas in each category thats why i have (4) textboxes...and as you can see i separate the textboxes from the php code because i have plans for it and use javascript for each texboxes.

In my current code its not working and i get an error that says: "Notice: Undefined index: code in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 19"

my current code:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="Zebra_Dialog-master/public/javascript/zebra_dialog.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Zebra_Dialog-master/public/css/default/zebra_dialog.css" type="text/css">
<link type="text/css" href="jqueryui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<?php
include('include/connect.php');
$batchcode = $_POST['code'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT aic,batchcode,address,name FROM tb_app WHERE batchcode LIKE '$batchcode'");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $aic[] = $rows['aic'];
    $name[] = $rows['name'];
    $address[] = $rows['address'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
Search Batchcode:<input type="text" name="code" id="query" /><br />
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
aic: <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $aic[0] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $aic[1] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $aic[2] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $aic[3] ?>" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Name List: <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name[0] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name[1] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name[2] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name[3] ?>" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Address: <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $address[0] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $address[1] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $address[2] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $address[3] ?>" /> <br />
</td>
</form>
<!--search function code-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#query").autocomplete({
        source : 'search.php',
        select : function(event,ui){
            $("#query").html(ui.item.value);
        }
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

search.php code:

```
<?php

$q = $_GET['term'];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT batchcode FROM tb_app WHERE batchcode LIKE '$q%'");

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$data[]=array('value'=>$row['batchcode']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I want it to do is after searching and clicking to the specific batchcode in the search textbox the data will automatically shows in the textboxes.

Comment: Can you show us the data returned from the ajax call to search.php please?

Comment: which one is line 19 in the original file?

Comment: @Relequestual ok w8 il update the code

Comment: @thilo.dev the $batchcode = $_POST['code'];

Answer (score 0):

Woah Woah Woah Chappy, direct POST data to sql queries a big no no..

Your error on the other hand is caused because the Global Post array has no array index called 'code'. Mainly because no post data has been sent to the page yet.

You would need to wrap all of that in a if statement.

```
if(isset($_POST['code'])){
///Logic.
```

I would do some reading on mysql injections and sanatising post data first though.

Comment: it solved that problem but the data still not showing up in the texboxes (aic)(name)(address)

Comment: Does your query return three results? What are the values in the results when you print them out?

Comment: if i type 2 in the (batchcode)texbox the value for aic,name and address will show in the textboxes.

Comment: I would: 

    print_r(mysql_fetch_array($query)); 
    //Make sure your query returns results and post the results here

Comment: got an error inside all the texboxes for(aic)(name)(address) here is the error inside their textboxes...Error(aic): "<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: aic in <b>", Error(name):  "Undefined variable: name in <b>", Error(address): "<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: address in <b>"

Comment: Maybe try this matey: 
http://pastebin.com/f42iNtYW
I've written it out in a bit more of a friendly manner, although untested Im affraid, at work and I dont have your db/the time to set one up. 

After typing it out i'd review a few things, looks like your html mark up is pretty wacky.

Comment: dude i dont want to loop my textboxes because they have unique name that ill be using later on in my javascript.